# Go Unmarshalling Response from API

Tags: go, backend, unmarshalling

I have been working with Go and the Bitmex API.

I have the following Bitmex api endpoint:

```
https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/leaderboard
```

This returns an array of JSON objects structured as follows.

```
[
  {
    "name": "string",
    "isRealName": true,
    "profit": 0
  }
]
```

However I get the following incorrect representation of the JSON when I marshal it.

```
[{0 false } {0 false } ... ]
```

I know my HTTP request is going through, as when I print the `response.Body` I get the following

```
[{"profit":256915996199,"isRealName":true,"name":"angelobtc"} ... ]
```

Here is the struct I am using to store the marshaled data.

```
type LeaderboardResponse struct {
    profit float64 `json:"profit"`
    isRealName bool `json:"isRealName"`
    name string `json:"name"`
}
```

And my main method

```
func main() {
    response, errorResponse := http.Get("https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/leaderboard")
    if response.Status == "200 OK"{
        if errorResponse != nil {
        fmt.Printf("The HTTP request failed with error %s\n",errorResponse)
        } else {
            body, errorBody := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
            if errorBody != nil {
                fmt.Println("There was an error retrieving the body", errorBody)
            } else {
                leaderboard := []LeaderboardResponse{}
                json.Unmarshal([]byte(body),&leaderboard)
                if leaderboard != nil {
                    fmt.Println(leaderboard);
                    //The result of the statement above and the one below are different 
                    fmt.Println(string(body))
                } else {
                    fmt.Println("leaderboard array is undefined")
                }
                defer response.Body.Close()
            }
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Response received with status ", string(response.Status))
    }
}
```

It appears that the values of struct have not been modifies despite it being assigned the marshaled JSON body

How do I fix this issue?

Furthermore,

- How do I add my API credentials to the HTTP request?
- How do I access the response header and marshal it?

Comment: make the fields in LeaderboardResponse start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: The fields have to be exported (first character upper case).

Comment: Thank-you @superfell

Comment: BTW it if recommended to check for error and return if there is an error, or if there is no - continue without adding additional indentation. I can't find any online reference to that statement, but it is in the [go book](http://gopl.io) and you can find example of such style [here](https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch5/outline2/outline.go#L24) and [here](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go)